# FocusReason in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I noticed that when calling `QtWidgets.setFocus`, I get a warning in PyCharm saying that it expects a `Qt.FocusReason` rather than a Boolean. Indeed, the documentation for this method also states that it takes a `Qt.FocusReason`. But for the life of me, I can't find any information on this for PyQt5.

```
myPlainTextEdit.setFocus(True)
```

The method works perfectly fine by passing in a Boolean, but I'm wondering if this is perhaps some legacy from PyQt4, or just an anomaly? I noticed that on the [PyQt Sourceforge Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#FocusReason-enum), which seems to be for PyQt4, that it says to get `FocusReason` from `QFocusEvent`. In attempting to do this, I get another warning; `Expected type 'FocusReason', got 'Type' instead.` This raises a TypeError, as one might expect.

```
myPlainTextEdit.setFocus(QtGui.QFocusEvent.ActionAdded)
```

The [PyQt5 documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/) does not appear to contain a page for `Qt.FocusReason`. As this is extremely pedantic, I'm not overly concerned if there is no solution. I am interested to know what causes this. Is it possible to pass a Qt FocusReason to `QtWidgets.setFocus` in the first place?

Comment: In python `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so there's no real mystery here. There has never been a `setFocus(bool)` overload. There has always been `setFocus()` and `clearFocus()`, and then `setFocus(Qt:FocusReason)` was added in Qt4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 functions called `setFocus()` that every widget supports:

- [`void QWidget::setFocus(Qt::FocusReason reason)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus)
- [`void QWidget::setFocus()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1)

You are referring to the first. So let's analyze what you point out:

- *The method works perfectly fine by passing in a Boolean*

It works but it does not imply that it is correct, first [`Qt::FocusReason`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusReason-enum) is an enumeration, that is to say that each element that belongs is associated to a number:

> ```
> Qt::MouseFocusReason          0   A mouse action occurred.
> Qt::TabFocusReason            1   The Tab key was pressed.
> Qt::BacktabFocusReason        2   A Backtab occurred. The input for this may include the Shift or Control keys; e.g. Shift+Tab.
> Qt::ActiveWindowFocusReason   3   The window system made this window either active or inactive.
> Qt::PopupFocusReason          4   The application opened/closed a pop-up that grabbed/released the keyboard focus.
> Qt::ShortcutFocusReason       5   The user typed a labels buddy shortcut
> Qt::MenuBarFocusReason        6   The menu bar took focus.
> Qt::OtherFocusReason          7   Another reason, usually application-specific.
> ```

so when passing a Boolean it will convert it to an integer, False to 0 and True to 1, so `setFocus(True)` equals `setFocus(QtCore.Qt.TabFocusReason)`.

- *In attempting to do this, I get another warning; Expected type 'FocusReason', got 'Type' instead. This raises a TypeError, as one might expect.*

  ```
  myPlainTextEdit.setFocus(QtGui.QFocusEvent.ActionAdded)
  ```

As you realize `QtGui.QFocusEvent.ActionAdded` does not belong to that list, so it throws the error. You have to use the values from the previous list by changing `::` by `.` and prefixing it with `QtCore` since it belongs to that submodule, for example:

```
myPlainTextEdit.setFocus(QtCore.Qt.MouseFocusReason)
```

**Plus:**

If you just want to establish that the widget has the focus you should call the second function:

```
myPlainTextEdit.setFocus()
```

And for clean use [`clearFocus()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#clearFocus).